# Using core library set variable in Apache Tiles

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, tiles, apache-tiles

**I have one template JSP page:**

```jsp
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <c:set var="temp" scope="request" value="" />
    <tile:insertAttribute name="header"/>
    <tile:insertAttribute name="body"/>
    <tile:insertAttribute name="footer"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**My template XML is below:**

```xml
<tiles-definitions>

    <definition name="home" extends="template">
        <put-attribute name="temp" value="home" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/pages/home.jsp" />  
    </definition>

    <definition name="template" template="/WEB-INF/templates/template.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="temp" />
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/pages/includes/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body"  />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/pages/includes/footer.jsp" />
    </definition>
<tiles-definitions>
```

**My question:**

When I have set `"home"` value in `"temp"` name in home definition, I want to get this `"home"` value in header page and footer page so I am do `${temp}` but I haven't found `"home"` value.

It's possible?
If yes then how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `tiles` to print attribute to JSP and set to the request scope variable or create a request scope variable with `tile:useAttribute`. For example in the first case you can do

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <c:set var="temp" scope="request"><tile:getAsString name="temp"/></c:set>
    <tile:insertAttribute name="header"/>
    <tile:insertAttribute name="body"/>
    <tile:insertAttribute name="footer"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up `Jstl` core tags in `tiles` tag.

Use

```
<tiles:getAsString name="temp" />
```

instead of

```
<c:set var="temp" scope="request" value="" />
```

Refer https://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/basic/pages.html